# Expl3 syntax command not working

Tags: macros, expl3

I have written a command in `expl3` syntax, but I can't figure out what is wrong with it (I'm new to `expl3` synatx, but decided to try it).

I want  the command `\wantedcontact[<optinal>]{<mandatory>}` to be equivalent to `\placetextbox{0.036}{0.369}{{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\color{wanted} <mandatory> }}` when the optional argument `reward` or no optional argument is given.
When `noreward` is given as an argument, it should produce `\placetextbox{0.036}{0.103}{{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\color{wanted} <mandatory> }}`.

I tried to set the default optional argument to `reward` by self referencing the function. I used `\text_lowercase:n { #1 }` so that an optional input `ReWaRd` would still produce the same as `reward`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Stuff from .sty file:
\definecolor{wanted}{HTML}{3D2113}

\RequirePackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand{\placetextbox}[3]{% \placetextbox{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
        \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},%
        \LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{tabular}{l}#3\end{tabular}}}
  }%
}%

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \wantedcontact { o m }
        { \textbox_placement:ne { \str_foldcase:n {#1} } { #2 } }

\msg_new:nnnn { wantedcontact } { unsupported-argument }
    % When not using an accepted entry
  { Unsupported~ entry~ field~ `#1'~ }
  { Only~entries~'reward'~or~'noreward'~allowed. }

\tl_new:N  \l__page_placement_default_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l__page_placement_default_tl { reward }


\cs_new_protected:Npn \textbox_placement:nn #1#2
    {
      \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
      { 
        \textbox_placement:nn {\l__page_placement_default_tl}{ #2 }
      }
    {
      {
    \str_case:nnF { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }
      {
        { reward  } { \placetextbox{0.036}{0.369}{ {\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\color{wanted} #2} } }
        { noreward } { \placetextbox{0.036}{0.103}{ {\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\color{wanted} #2} } }
      }
        { \msg_error:nn { wantedcontact } { unsupported-argument } { #1 } }
      }
    }}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \textbox_placement:nn {ne}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Hello.

\wantedcontact{hello}

\placetextbox{0.5}{0.5}{Hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the error is `! Undefined control sequence.
\wantedcontact code #1#2->\textbox_placement:ne` as you only defined the `:nn` version.

Comment: at first you need to generate  the variant: `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \textbox_placement:nn {ne} `

Comment: Thanks. @UlrikeFischer But now I get the ``unsupported-argument``-error, regardless of what optional argument I use (also get this error for no optional arguments).

Comment: `\str_case:nnF { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }` will literally take the string `\text_lowercase:n` plus that for `#1`. You want to expand the string, so `\str_case:eeF`, you also should not use a `text` command here: you are string folding, so use `\str_casefold:n`.

Comment: I replaced  ``\str_case:nnF { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }`` with ``\str_case:nnF { #1  }`` but still get error. What else is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\tl_if_novalue:nTF` will always return false, because you pass `\str_foldcase:n { #1 }`.

You also want another variant, namely `\textbox_placement:Vn`.

I made some other fixes, check them against your code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Stuff from .sty file:
\definecolor{wanted}{HTML}{3D2113}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

% \placetextbox{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
    \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},%
    \LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{tabular}{l}#3\end{tabular}}}
  }%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \wantedcontact { o m }
 {
  \textbox_placement:ne { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { wantedcontact } { unsupported-argument }
    % When not using an accepted entry
  { Unsupported~ entry~ field~ `#1'~ }
  { Only~entries~'reward'~or~'noreward'~allowed. }

\tl_const:Nn  \c__page_placement_default_tl { reward }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \textbox_placement:nn #1#2
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
   { 
    \textbox_placement:Vn \c__page_placement_default_tl { #2 }
   }
   {
    \str_case_e:nnF { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
     {
      { reward   } { \placetextbox{0.036}{0.369}{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\color{wanted}#2} }
      { noreward } { \placetextbox{0.036}{0.103}{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\color{wanted}#2} }
     }
     { \msg_error:nnn { wantedcontact } { unsupported-argument } { #1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \textbox_placement:nn {ne,Vn}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Hello.

\wantedcontact{hello}

\wantedcontact[noreward]{hello}

\wantedcontact[foo]{hello}

\placetextbox{0.5}{0.5}{Hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can you modify it so that it accepts ``\par`` in ``#2``?

Comment: @Vebjorn You're wrapping the second argument in `tabular`, aren't you?

Comment: I get the errors: ``! Paragraph ended before \wantedcontact  was complete.`` and ``Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`` I tried to replace ``\makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{tabular}{l}#3\end{tabular}}`` by ``\parbox{\textwidth}{#3}``.

Comment: @Vebjorn `\NewDocumentCommand{\wantedcommand}{o +m}{...}`