# Modify expl3 command to take \vspace in argument

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion

How can this command (`\wantedcontact`) be modified to be able to take a `\vspace{ }` command in its argument? The other command `\placetextbox` works fine when given `\vspace` in its argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{wanted}{HTML}{3D2113}

\RequirePackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand{\placetextbox}[3]{% \placetextbox{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
        \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},%
        \LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\parbox{\textwidth}{#3}}
  }%
}%

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \wantedcontact { o +m }
 {
  \textbox_placement:ne { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { wantedcontact } { unsupported-argument }
    % When not using an accepted entry
  { Unsupported~ entry~ field~ `#1'~ }
  { Only~entries~'reward'~or~'noreward'~allowed. }

\tl_const:Nn  \c__page_placement_default_tl { reward }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \textbox_placement:nn #1#2
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
  { 
    \textbox_placement:Vn \c__page_placement_default_tl { #2 }
  }
  {
    \str_case_e:nnF { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
     {
      { reward   } { \placetextbox{0.036}{0.369}{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\color{wanted}#2} }
      { noreward } { \placetextbox{0.036}{0.103}{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\color{wanted}#2} }
     }
     { \msg_error:nnn { wantedcontact } { unsupported-argument } { #1 } }
  }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \textbox_placement:nn {ne,Vn}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Hello.

\wantedcontact[ReWaRd]{
a\vspace{2cm}\\b
}

\placetextbox{0.036}{0.369}{a\vspace{2cm}\\b}

\end{document}
```

May be useful to see: [Expl3 syntax command not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663815/199568)

Comment: `e`  is like edef you can not use arbitrary latex constructs. Do you really need full expansion here? why not use the base `nn` form?

Comment: If I replace `\textbox_placement:ne` by `\textbox_placement:nn` it runs without error and typesets  hello a and b

Comment: @DavidCarlisle seems like I did not. Everything works fine when I replaced ``e`` with ``n``. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` is like `\edef` you can not use arbitrary latex constructs. Do you really need full expansion here? why not use the base `nn` form?
 
If I replace `\textbox_placement:ne` by `\textbox_placement:nn` it runs without error and typesets hello a and b